# Does Mule Anypoint Studio have partial deployment?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

It is really time-consuming to restart the flow to test during the development. It stops and starts up the server all the time. Does Anypoint Studio have a partial deploy option? Or at least a way to deploy my own built project to the server? Now it is something close to deploying it to the remote through bamboo :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to restart the server, you can keep editing your application and saving the changes and the hot deployment will redeploy only the app without restarting the server. The only issue is if you add new files or classes you may need to restart so that these files get added to the app on the server, otherwise, it should work.

Comment: I added a logger and do not see any changes when I saved the flow and waited in Anypoint Studio.

Comment: In `src/main/app/mule-deploy.properties`, does the properties `redeployment.enabled=true` exists and is `true` ? If not, make sure it is and retry. Normally the solution provided by Matias works

Comment: Yes I have `redeployment.enabled=true` line in my `mule-deploy.properties` file . It is a maven project, how does it change things?

Comment: @PierreB.  ^^^  do you have a resource in this case?

Comment: If the reployment.enabled properties is false, your app won't automatically restart on change. But in your case it should, strange. Did you try using the newest Studio and Mule version?